# Redis compressing string values in .net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redis, gzipstream

In my app I want to compress the data that get stored in redis string keys.
I don't want to compress all of them though because small data values don't compress well and I want to avoid the cpu overhead on them.

My question is how to detect that a value is compressed when I read the string key in order to perform decompression?

I tried some code to append a custom header to the zip stream but i didn't had any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern is to use a payload prefix combined with a delimiter.

For example, you could use a format like this:

```
[key];[encoding];[metatype];[version]\t[payload]
```

I use delimiters `;` and `\t` here. Choose other delimiters if you like them better. Ofcourse you must prevent these delimiters from occurring in your prefix tags themselves. `[payload]` contains for example binary data, string data, whatever. `[encoding]` can for example be `zip`,[`msgpack`](http://msgpack.org/),`utf8`,`base64`,`json` (just some ideas).

The benefit of using a payload prefix is that you don't have to deserialize or uncompress the payload itself to use it as an entity. In Redis-Lua for example, you can't unzip. But you can do a simple read of the preload prefix, and respond to client requests. Even if you *can* deserialize inside Redis-Lua, like JSON or [MsgPack](http://redis.io/commands/eval) formats, you might not *want* to do that because of performance reasons.

There are other options ofcourse. If you don't like prefixes with delimiters, you could also put the payload and encoding-tag in an array, and serialize it as MsgPack. Or, use JSON for the prefix, then a null character, then the payload. Or even (a bit more memory efficient): use 4 or 8 bytes for the prefix size, MsgPack for the prefix, and use the prefix size to determine where the payload starts (which might even be MsgPack as well).

Final word of advice: don't mess with the payload itself (like altering the zip header), that's bound to get you in a whole lot of unnecessary trouble.

Hope this helps, TW

Comment: I think that I got what you mean, please correct me if I'm wrong. I will create another stream, write the prefix and the copy the compressed stream.... Am I right?

Comment: That's one way to do it (and maybe that's the easiest way to do it in C# / BookSleeve / StackExchange.Redis, whichever you are using). You can also write a custom serializer for your object. The result, which you send to Redis, is always a simple bytearray. Redis keys/values/strings are always binary safe, it's up to you how you use it.